# Need to Base64 Decode This String

Tags: php, base64

I tried decoding this base64 string so many times but every time i get some parts that decode fine but other parts are all gibberish, can anyone help me ?

```
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
```

If you can do it can you please explain how you did it, thank you !

Comment: Well it's probably not a valid base64 string. Are you sure that's what it was encoded with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update, see [Gumbo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352214/need-to-base64-decode-this-string/2352298#2352298). It seems to be encoded as [base 64 for URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications). The method I showed below seems to work for this specific file, but it would be better to do as Gumbo suggested as it will be more robust.

```
print (b.replace('-','/').replace('_','+')+'===').decode('base64')
```

---

Old answer.

How about this:

```
b = 'PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIj8_DQo8cm9vdD4NCgk8YTQ2Nzg2NT4NCgkJPHQ_DQoJCQk2DQoJCTwvdD4NCgkJPHU'

import sys
for l in b.split('_'):
    sys.stdout.write((l+'==').decode('base64')+'>')
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
        <a467865>
                <t>
                        6
                </t>
                <u>
                        http://milledrive.com/videos/41841/Shutter_Island_2_2.html
                </u>
                <i>
```

etc...

Comment: replacing _DQo with /Pg0 yields better results however there is still many parts that are not correct.

Comment: even /Pg0 yields an extra '?' that should not be there. . .

Comment: I love that it's a link to a screener of the movie... score!

Comment: The mapping is `_`⇔`+`, `-`⇔`/`.

Answer (score 7):

It seems that this Base64 code used the [URL safe variant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications) with `_` and `-` instead of `+` and `/` respectively (with this exact association). So just map these characters back before decoding and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems it wasn't properly encoded, my decoder receives an error.